# REST-ish URI design for multiple dependent resources

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I'm trying to design a REST-ish based Web Service to interface with a farm animal management system I am working on.

To explain the problem in detail, I have a collection of **animals** belonging to a farm. Each animal has its own information - such as name, ID number, breed age, etc. Therefore, I would assume a URI such as the following would suit:

```
/animals               <- retrieve list of animals
/animals/{animal-id}   <- Retrieve only one animal
/animals?breed=sheep   <- Search/query
```

The problem arises when I try to link in other dependent resources to each animal. An animal **can** have a collection of *weight* information, as well as what I call *comments* (observations made for a particular animal). Each of these are dependent and only exist to that one particular animal, but are themselves a resource I want to access.

The easiest approach IMO would be to nest the resources within the animal URI:

```
/animals/{animal-id}/weights
/animals/{animal-id}/comments
```

However, I see a need to access and query the *weights* and *comments* directly, without referencing the animal. Examples in usage would be to retrieve the most recent (or all) weight(s) from all animals of a particular breed `...?breed=sheep` or even return weights/comments for a selection of individual animal ID's `...?animals={ID1},{ID2},{...}`.

Further complications arise when I want to add one comment to multiple animals at once. (please excuse my representation of a POST and JSON)

```
POST ....
{
  "comment":"Animal moved to paddock B",
  "animals":[{id1}, {id2}, ...]
}
```

I understand that the obvious solution to this problem would be to GET and POST (for example) to **each** animal that I wanted to retrieve/edit. I would prefer not to do this though, as eventually I want this service accessed from mobile devices, and therefore decreasing the number of calls seems wise.

I believe that the web standards allow CSV in the URI, so something like this could work,

```
/animals/{id1},{id2},{..}/weights
```

But, I am expecting cases where ten(s) of animals may need to be referenced at once (or queried), and that would lead to a messy and unfriendly URI.

My current perceived solution is to expose *weights* and *comments* as their own resource, which allows me to access and query them directly

```
/weights
/weights/{weight-id}
/weights?breed=sheep
```

and even post directly to the collection

```
POST /comments
{
  "comment":"Animal moved to paddock B",
  "animals":[{id1}, {id2}, ...]
}
```

But what would `/animals/{animal-id}/weights` return? Is it even needed, or would I just reference a link to the `/weights?animal={animal-id}` resource itself? But is it okay to link to a queried resource?

Am I making one redundant, or just providing "another" way to access the information?

Is there something that I am doing wrong, am I letting my database influence my service model, or am I just missing the point completely?

I am quite new to this, and have read quite a few contradicting arguments regarding these issues, and so am quite confused as to what is best for my requirements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to define top level resources for your other entities if you want to address them as such (`/weights`, `/comments` etc). You can then POST to those endpoints in a batch fashion.

```
POST /comments

{
    "animals" : [
        {"id" : 1},
        {"id" : 2},
        {"id" : 3},
        {"id" : 4},
    ],
    "commentText" : "Sent to Hamburger Hamlet"
}
```

Note that including long lists of id's in your URL is not good design for several reasons, including that most browsers and HTML proxies have restrictions on URL length (the good rule of thumb is to try and keep URL lengths at 2083 characters in length or less).

Comment: Thanks @Perception, well explained. I was worried about the URL length.
I'm still not sure how I would reference/link these (weight/comments) from a particular animal? Something like in the animal response: `"weights" : {"ref":"/weights?animal={id}"}` ?
Or should I list each value individually?

Comment: For ease of designing client applications I would do both. Include a `"weights"` attribute with each animal, containing a summary of just the most important information. Then include links for the full weight resource in the refs section.

Comment: Thanks @Perception, I think I'll give that a go. It seems the most straight forward approach so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues to you, but in the end we were able to remove the complexities you are getting by having specific url namespaces (so to speak) for different user types using the API.

For example it might be a farm worker client app that would perform your /weights, /comments actions (POST, PUT, DELETE etc) that you are describing, so you could keep their functionality clean via something like:

```
/farmworkers/comments
/farmworkers/weights
```

And then still keep the `/animals/{animal-id}/weights` URL within some other "namespace".

Another thing to consider is embedding resources using something like the HAL format (http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), which could allow you to embed multiple animal resources within the request etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I had looked at HAL early on, but now I see that it could be quite useful. Your idea of using different 'namespaces' is interesting, and I might even apply that elsewhere.

Comment: Another tip that really helped us was to write documentation up front for how the API would work in the context of a client application writer.  Forces you to think of exactly what it is you need to develop and also makes writing any documentation less boring :)

Comment: That's a nice way to think of it. I had been trying to put it all on paper first, but this is an interesting approach. Thanks.